# Does the startDelay property in a SimpleTrigger delay every time the job is ran, or simply the first job that is ran?

Tags: java, spring

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <!-- 10 seconds -->
  <property name="startDelay" value="10000"/>
    <!-- repeat every 50 seconds -->
  <property name="repeatInterval" value="50000"/>
</bean>
```

In this simple trigger the repeatInterval is set for every 50 seconds. However, the startDelay is set for 10 seconds. Does this startDelay get applied every time at the beginning of a job (effectively meaning the job starts every 40 seconds?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SimpleTriggerBean.html
 *startDelay  is the delay before starting the job for the first time.*

So, that means that your job will start after 10 seconds after `start`, then it will repeat each 50 seconds.